# How INSERT and UPDATE works based on IF condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Curious to know one simple SQL concept in SQL Server.
I have two tables, based on certain IF condition , I would like to update and insert data from different tables.I'm using below query for this in side a stored procedure.

```
IF( SELECT COUNT(colname) FROM [dbo].[Table_BKP] WHERE colname LIKE ('%Dear(DEC''D)444-0292/555-4528C%'))> 0 
BEGIN   
 ;WITH Dear AS 
(
SELECT ID,colname,SUBSTRING(colname,PATINDEX('%(DEC''D)%',colname),LEN(colname)-1) AS colname_4SUPPL,LEFT(colname,PATINDEX('%(DEC''D)%',colname)-1) AS colname_4MAIN
FROM [dbo].[Table_BKP] WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(colname)) LIKE ('Dear(DEC''D)444-0292/555-4528C')
) SELECT * INTO Dear_ FROM Dear

 UPDATE A SET A.colname = B.colname_4MAIN FROM Table AS A INNER JOIN 
  Dear_ AS B ON A.ID = B.ID 
  INSERT INTO Table_SUPPL(ID,colnameMSC,[SOURCE],[TARGET])
 SELECT ID,replace(colname_4SUPPL,'(DEC''D)',''),'colname','colnameMSC' 
 FROM Dear_ 
END
```

update statement is working fine and data is getting updated into the required table.However, the data is not getting inserted into the required table.

But, when I changed the sequence as below, it worked perfectly.

```
IF( SELECT COUNT(colname) FROM [dbo].[Table_BKP] WHERE colname LIKE ('%Dear(DEC''D)444-0292/555-4528C%'))> 0 
     BEGIN  
   ;WITH Dear AS 
(
SELECT ID,colname,SUBSTRING(colname,PATINDEX('%(DEC''D)%',colname),LEN(colname)-1) AS colname_4SUPPL,LEFT(colname,PATINDEX('%(DEC''D)%',colname)-1) AS colname_4MAIN
FROM [dbo].[Table_BKP] WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(colname)) LIKE ('Dear(DEC''D)444-0292/555-4528C')
) SELECT * INTO Dear_ FROM Dear

   INSERT INTO Table_SUPPL(ID,colnameMSC,[SOURCE],[TARGET]) SELECT 
   ID,replace(colname_4SUPPL,'(DEC''D)',''),'colname','colnameMSC' FROM 
  Dear_ 
  UPDATE A SET A.colname = B.colname_4MAIN FROM Table AS A INNER JOIN 
Dear_ AS B ON A.ID = B.ID 

END
```

Why, the formar quesry is not working as expected? And, the later one [just after changing sequesnce (1st INSERT then Update)]; Its working perfectly...How SQL Server manages these sequence? Could anyone please clarify this simple doubt? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any triggers linked to the invoved tables? Is this code inside a try/catch that might be jumping to the catch block? Make sure that your blocks BEGIN and END are correctly placed.